# Cannot GET / Node JS Amazon EC2 server issues

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-ec2, server

In my app.js file

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${process.env.PORT || 8080}!`));
```

In my webpack.config.js file

```
devServer: {
   port: 3000,
   open: true,
   proxy: {
     '/api': 'http://localhost:8080'
   }
}
```

In /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default on my EC2 instance

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  _;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://[private ip]:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

EDIT: Full app.js file

```
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static('dist'));
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${process.env.PORT || 8080}!`));

app.post('/api/[route]', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const seq = await sequelize();
    const file = await [...];
  } catch (err) {
    return next(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: try this in nginx `proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;`

Comment: @Ahmad still the same error

Comment: Sorry, your webpack proxy is serving the app on 3000, i think your proxy pass must be `http://localhost:3000`

Comment: I changed it to this and received ```502 Bad Gateway```

Comment: please share your app.js code, does your code has an endpoint for / ?

Comment: @Ahmad see my edit, i added more from my app.js. There are in total 3 routes using app.post, i only posted one as an example.

Comment: Your proxy pass is going to be `http://localhost:8080/` and your endpoints will be accessible at [serverip]/api/[route].
Because you do not have any route with direct / in your api, that's why node app is sending cannot GET /

Comment: if app.js file runs on port 8080 then /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default should be on localhost:8080, you can use PM2 process manager, All you need is to run node locally on localhost and put that port number in  proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;

Answer (score 0):

The correct config was

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  _;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

I believe i had installed pm2 incorrectly at the beginning, because both the nginx server and pm2 were trying to listen on port 80. So i did a fresh install of everything, and voila it works now.